# multiple select menus and if statement

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I have 2 select menus that can both change the data displayed on the page.  Right now I have the code written that changes the displayed data based upon one of the select menus being changed, and it works fine.  That function starts out with a variable set to the selection of the menu, and then an ajax call is made.  I want to be able to listen for a change on *either* select menu and assign the variable to the id of the select menu that changed.  So something like this:

```
var category = if( //first select menu is the one that changes) [
    //assign that id to category. 
} else if( //second select menu is the one that changes) {
    //assign that id to category.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you assign a listener to several select menus, the one being changed is always referenced in `this`.

```
var category = null;

$('#select-1, #select-2').change(function() {
    category = this.id;
});
```

Comment: that doesn't work for me.  The variable I'm trying to assign is in a function that's triggered by the onchange event of each of the select menus.  So I need to detect which select menu fired the event and assign the id of that menu option to the variable.

Comment: @hyphen: I don't see why that should be an issue. Please post a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) demonstrating your problem and I'll have a look at it.

Comment: actually, I found a type-o.  That did work.  thanks!